# New monitor, older graphics card - will they work together?

Tags: graphics-cards, monitors

I'm thinking about getting a large monitor that also can be used as a television.

The monitor I'm thinking about (Aorus FV43U) has DisplayPort 1.4, HDMI 2.1, and USB-C ports. I have an older graphics card (Geforce GTX 1070 ti) and I'm trying to understand if the monitor will even work to it's full potential here. As far as I understood it, my graphics card has no HDMI 2.1 capabilities but has DisplayPort 1.4. Would this be sufficient?

I'm not well versed with hardware, and actually had the wrong cable on my last monitor, so I'm trying to make sure the configuration actually works before I buy the monitor.

Comment: DP 1.4 is good enough, even HDMI 2.0.

Comment: At 4k, you'll be limited to 120 Hz of the 144 Hz available due to the DisplayPort 1.4s lack of UHBR support.
Since you monitor doesn't support DisplayPort 2.0, you'd need a graphics card with HDMI 2.1 to make full use of your monitors capabilities.
However, you'll be unlikely to hit over 120 FPS at 4k at any relevant game even with a 3090 anyways.

tl;dr: Will work, but at 120 Hz instead of 144.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AORUS FV43U will be at its full potential with the following display mode:
`3840 x 2160 (UHD), 10-bit, 144 Hz, with Freesync and HDR`

DisplayPort 1.4 on the GTX 1070ti will support the following mode at maximum:
`3840 x 2160 (UHD), 10-bit, 120 Hz, with Freesync and HDR`

I would say that is close enough, and even at 60Hz this monitor is going to look amazing. If you're playing newer games in UHD then the 1070ti might not reach 120 FPS anyway. You can always change the display mode to make some trade-offs too:

`2560 x 1440, 10-bit, 144 Hz, with Freesync and HDR`
or
`3840 x 2160, 8-bit, 144 Hz, with Freesync`